# jenkins job does not finish even though it is successful

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a Jenkins pipeline job in which I give a windows batch command to start my hybris server. Normally also if hybris is started from a command prompt, the server window (command window) will keep the process running and it does not exit. With the same thing happeining in Jenkins, the job never ends even though the server has successfully started. Pls suggest how I can get the server running, yet exit out of the job succesfully. Below is the pipeline script:

```
 node {
       stage 'ServerStop'
        echo 'Stop the server if previously running'
        bat '''call D:\\path_to_hybris\\hybris\\bin\\platform\\hybrisserver.bat stop
    EXIT /B 0'''

        stage 'Checkout'
        echo 'Checkout related script'

       stage 'Build'
       echo 'Build script here'


        stage 'ServerStart'
        bat '''call D:\\path_to_hybris\\hybris\\bin\\platform\\start.bat
        '''}
```

Comment: You can start your batch command as an independent process. Instead of `call` use `start`. `start` will start the batch script program in a new window and it will be independent of current running process.

Comment: Yes, that worked :)